# Add new field to an Array of type object to a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

See example below (json format from mongochef). I need to add a new field to each element in our collection called isReadOnly (bool). How would I do this? I can easily add it to the root of the document but battling to do it within each array element.

```
{ 
"_id" : "fda42f22-0fa4-4e4a-94bf-245b1124c8b9", 
"_t" : "FullConfiguration", 
"DeviceConfigName" : "Illinois", 
"Elements" : [
    {
        "_t" : "NumberConfigurationElement", 
        "AsciiConfigNumber" : NumberInt(10), 
        "DataType" : NumberInt(1), 
        "ByteOffset" : NumberInt(0), 
        "Name" : "alcohol_limit", 
        "Description" : "The alcohol limit of the device (ug/l)", 
        "AckResponse" : "HT-CONFG,010,00119", 
        "DevicePart" : NumberInt(1), 
        "Value" : NumberInt(119), 
        "DefaultValue" : NumberInt(119), 
        "Min" : NumberInt(50), 
        "Max" : NumberInt(500)
    }, .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this(if your collection is called 'coll'):

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(e) {
    var t = e.Elements;
    t.forEach(function(e) {
        e.isReadOnly=false
    });
    db.coll.update({ _id : e._id }, { $set: { Elements : t } } );
})
```

Comment: This pushes an additional document of `{ isReadOnly: false }` to the existing elements array, not to each document inside the array.  There is an open issue on the MongoDB JIRA about this, I think the only way to do this is inside JavaScript using Mongoose or another MongoDB driver.

Comment: @dyouberg there is better way to do this and you probably don't want to iterate the cursor like that as shown in the answer because there is a possibility for race condition and remember Murphy's law

Answer (score 0):

@Styvane , this is what I came up with, it still seems a bit hacky.

```
var query = {
    Elements: {
        $elemMatch: {
            _t: { $exists: true },
            isReadOnly: { $exists: false }
        }
    }
};

while (db.collection.find(query).count() > 0) {
    db.collection.update(
        query, 
        { $set: { "Elements.$.isReadOnly": true } }
    );    
}
```

Comment: This also is not good. This is *factually correct* in MongoDB 2.4 and even then, you can just iterate the cursor but instead a [snapshot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) of the curor. The best way to do this is with [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Answer (score 0):

@David I've working solution with MongoDB 3.6+.

```
db.collection.update({},
    { $set: { "Elements.$[].isReadOnly": false } }, { multi: true }
)
```

This command will add `isReadOnly = false` field in all `Element` array field of documents.

The `$position` modifier specifies the location in the array at which the `$push` operator inserts elements. Without the `$position` modifier, the `$push` operator inserts elements to the end of the array. See `$push` modifiers for more information.

More details you can find on [position operator docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)